# Redshift/SQL Query to do arithmetic based on value of column - get sales by inventory from two data points with multiple groups

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Amazon Redshift, named 'inventory'

This is a data pull from external systems. This happens twice a day, once in the morning (right at opening), and once right after closing. These are the location_id column below (there are multiple locations).

I want to figure out the total items sold based on column 'total_inventory'.

There is a column 'import_time' which has two possible values, 'am' and 'pm'.

All of this should by done by date, called 'import_date'

Data may look like this:

```
item_id | location_id | total_inventory | import_date | import_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
10123   | 3           | 10              | 2019-10-01  | am
10123   | 3           | 3               | 2019-10-01  | pm
10123   | 3           | 7               | 2019-10-02  | am
10123   | 3           | 6               | 2019-10-02  | pm
```

I would ideally like to be able to see results of total_sold such as:

```
item_id | location_id | total_sold | import_date
------------------------------------------------
10123   | 3           | 7          | 2019-10-01
10123   | 3           | 1          | 2019-10-02
```

Note: Daily start levels have nothing to do with previous stock levels as they are replenished over night.

Also note: I have inherited this issue, and if structural changes are required, I can do so, but if possible to avoid it would be helpful.

I have attempted to look at other answers where arithmetic is being done based on column values, but I did not see (or rather, understand) a fit that would work for me.

Full Transparency: My SQL skills are fairly weak as of late due to not using them in a long while, so please go easy on me if I have asked a foolish question.

Answer (score 1):

If the pm value is alway less than the am, you can do:

```
select import_date, item_id, location_id,
       max(total_inventory) - min(total_inventory)
from t
group by import_date, item_id, location_id;
```

However, I suspect yo really want conditional aggregation:

```
select import_date, item_id, location_id,
       (max(case when import_time = 'pm' then total_inventory else 0 end) -
        min(case when import_time = 'am' then total_inventory else end)
       )
from t
group by import_date, item_id, location_id;
```